# How can I return a pair from list of pairs in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I have a list that has pairs stored in it.

```
'((a (b 1))
  (b (c 2))
  (c (d 3))
  (d (e f)))

 (define    (compare-unit unit-to-check source)
  (cond ((null? source) '())
        ((equal? (car source) unit-to-check) (car source))))
```

In my program, I want to check if the search query is equivalent to a car of the pair in list and return the given pair.

For example, if the search query has `(a x)` and `(a (b 1))` has same car as `(a x)`, I would like to return `(a (b 1))`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a built-in procedure that does just what you need - it's called [`assoc`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._assoc%29%29):

```
(define (compare-unit unit-to-check source)
  (assoc (car unit-to-check) source))
```

For example:

```
(define source
  '((a (b 1))
    (b (c 2))
    (c (d 3))
    (d (e f))))

(compare-unit '(a x) source)
=> '(a (b 1))
```

Comment: And of course `(a (b 1))` is the returned value, not `'(a (b 1))` that some descendants of Scheme might display in their REPL.